# How to connect simultaneously to a wired internet and wired LAN network?

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, ethernet, wired

I am trying to set up my own personal "beowulf" cluster at home, and have 5 PCs running Ubuntu 14.04 that I would like to connect to eachother through a LAN and to the internet. These are old PCs though and so have no wifi. I have connected all of my PCs to an ethernet switch and then connected the switch to the internet. I can happily switch between the internet connection and the LAN, however I am not finding it possible for them to be connected simultaneously.

Here is a shot of `ifconfig` on the machine I want to be my master node

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:22:15:34:71:63  
          inet addr:10.42.0.1  Bcast:10.42.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::222:15ff:fe34:7163/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:451 errors:1 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:1
          TX packets:60 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:108843 (108.8 KB)  TX bytes:12399 (12.3 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:4104 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4104 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:318400 (318.4 KB)  TX bytes:318400 (318.4 KB)
```

I have clicked on `Edit Connections...` , clicked on my LAN network, clicked `Edit`, put in the valid mac address in `Device MAC address` and in the `IPv4 Settings` tab I changed method to `Manual`, clicked `Add` and set the Address to 10.0.0.2, Netmask to 255.255.255.0 and left Gateway blank. I've also clicked on Routes and checked the box for `Use this connection only for resources on its network`. Still, when I do the same on one of the slave nodes, I can't get them to connect unless they're both explicitly connected to the LAN network and are explicitly not connected to the internet. Here is a shot of route, while connected to the LAN:

```
danny@danny2:~$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.0.0.0       *               255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
danny@danny2:~$
```

and here is a shot of route when connected to the internet:

```
danny@danny2:~$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         FIOS_Quantum_Ga 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
danny@danny2:~$
```

All of the other machines in my network have ip addresses that I've given them in the `IPv4 Settings` tab of 10.0.0.1 up to 10.0.0.5. Any ideas on what I can do? I have scoured the internet, and can't seem to find anything where people have multiple **wired** connections they need to have connected simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

This is more a networking issue.

You wish to connect (at least) 2 networks: your LAN and the Internet.

The easiest way is of course using a router. It looks like your "switch" is a router, it is even a DHCP server. You may want to access advanced routing options to match your needs.

But as you mention a "primary" server, maybe you want it to act as a router? If so, having only one ethernet card is going to be a real challenge, but if you eager to learn, you can do this using virtual interfaces and creating your own routing tables.

I wouldn't try to do so using the network manager gui.

You're going to hate the /etc/network/interfaces file... your best starting point might be

```
 man 5 interfaces
```

then.

Comment: Right I eventually understood that only having one ethernet port wasn't going to be a good idea. I installed a PCI card for a second port - now my route table looks the first route table I posted, however with an **identical** line below it except eth0-->eth1. What do you think my next move is?

Comment: Your best move is to read this : http://www.techrepublic.com/article/understand-the-basics-of-linux-routing/ . You'll learn the basics of routing and how to make your own routing table. If you use static IP adresses (using a non routable networks such as 10.0.0.0 as you did), you'll have to use your main PC adress on eth1 (if eth1 is your LAN interface) as the default gateway. So the clients and the PC can talk to each other using 10.0.0.0 network and when they want to access a host outside this network they use your PC as a router which forwards the traffic to eth0 connected to the Internet.

Comment: If you wish to use non static IPs you'll have to install a DHCP server using your PC address as the default gateway as well.